# LabVIEW is overwriting captured images in a queue

Tags: image, parallel-processing, labview, vision

I'm using the vision routines to capture frames ("grab") from a 300fps GigE camera.  The camera can deliver frames a little faster than the HD can write them, so I'm capturing in one loop and sticking them in a queue which is read out in a second (adjacent/parallel) loop.  Everything goes fine until the first loop finishes (as far as I can tell), meaning that the data has all been acquired, most has been written, and the remainder just needs to be written out.  Unfortunately, all of the images left in the queue magically *retroactively* all end up with the same data, so the last part of the data set contains hundreds of static frames.

How do I avoid this behavior?  I assume that there's *some* resource I need to hold on to so that image buffer memory isn't reclaimed, but it's obviously *not* the images themselves.  (I do not do any explicit camera cleanup stuff there.)

Here's an ASCII-art depiction of what I'm doing (at least I hope this is the relevant part):

```
          +===============+   +==========+
-queue----@-------Insert--@---@-Empty?---@---Release queue
       |  # GrabImg-^     #   #  |       #
       |  #               #   #  Y->Stop #
       |  # i-(>n?)->Stop #   +==========+
       |  +===============+
       |
       |  +==============+
       \--@-Deleted?--Y  #
          #  |        |  #
          #  N->Get   |  #
          #      |    v  #
          #    Write Stop#
          +==============+
```

I'm using queue deletion to signal the end of the loop.  It's a bit sloppy, granted, so I could understand an off by *one* error, but not an off-by-2200 error, which is the worst that I've seen.  (And again, it *does* write all the images, they're just all the same at the end.)

Comment: where and when are the images in your consumer buffer, and when is the latter cleaned up?

Comment: @CharlesB - Does that edit provide enough information?

Comment: err, I'm not used to the way you do it. does grabimg copy the image on a new one? do you delete the image after write? Also in the edit menu you can create a png of selected objets of your diagram, and post the image here. Result PNG contains the LV code also, so it's a nice way to share LV code here

Comment: @CharlesB - Aha--you guessed it.  GrabImg is IMAQdx Image Grab, and an existing image is passed in. So there is only ever one image!  I inherited the code and didn't notice that the same image is put in the queue over and over again.  If you want to post something to the effect of "IMAQdx image grab copies over an existing image instead of creating a new one--you may not be putting separately-allocated images in the queue", I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a producer-consumer loop the producer needs to copy the image so that it's not overwritten at the next iteration if consumer hasn't processed it. GrabImg does not do this step, so you need to create a new one before each grab, and have the consumer take care of releasing each buffer it has processed.

Beware of memory issues though!